# Stop the Scroll in Dynamic Page with Selenium in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, infinite-scroll

Hello everyone i'm trying to use selenium and scrapy to scraping some information from https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index/discover?sid=396545663

I try different method, i use Selenium and setting PhantomJs like driver.
For scrolling down the page, it's a infinite scroll page, i use this instruction:

```
elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

For simulating the press of Page Down button, instead of the JavaScript function:

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Because this one "seems" load less elements in the page.

The main **problem** is how i can know when i have reached the bottom of the page? Is "Infinite Scroll" page so i can't know when it end i need to scroll down, but i don't have any element in the bottom to analyze.

Actually i use temporized cycle, but look really stupid.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually look for that "Loading..." indicator. [Wait for it](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) to be visible on every scroll, but if you'll get a `TimeoutException` - there was no loading indicator this time and there are no more items to load.

Sample implementation:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    # do the scrolling
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[. = 'Loading...']")))
    except TimeoutException:
        break  # not more posts were loaded - exit the loop
```

Not tested.

Comment: Thanks for your respose, however Yahoo dosn't have this kind of icon or any indicator of loading.

Comment: @RedVelvet it has, at the bottom when you scroll, look for the appearing "Loading ..." element, it has  `id="ya-infinite-scroll-message"` and "Loading ..." text.

Comment: thanks @alecxe i use  wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ya-infinite-scroll-message"))) and it works, but he stop after 80 questions... it's strange.

Comment: EDIT: It's a great solutions, the fault is of the website seems that load different number of elements any time so change every times.

Comment: @RedVelvet yeah, I am afraid that waiting for the "loading" indicator might not be reliable enough. I've seen your follow-up question and will take a look if I'll find time. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your help me, i'm a novice with this technique. If you find a solution please answer me in the follow-up question. :)

Answer (score 0):

As example you can create some parallel thread witch will check page for ajax requests. If time between requests is more often than 10 seconds -- you on the end of page. Have no other idea.